# Appended href Attribute not Working - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, href

I'm setting up an alert that will slide in at the top of a page.  In the code the href attribute doesn't seem to be adding the web address. I'm not getting any errors in my console, but can't seem to find out what is causing this.  When you click on the 'Go to Google' button I've set up as a test, it should take you to Google, but it doesn't?  The code and Codepen are below, any help would be amazing.

Codepen is here: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/ZyGrrR

HTML

```
<div id="header">Original Header</div>
```

CSS

```
   * {font-family: arial;
 line-height: 100px;}

#header {width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background: red;
color: white;
text-align: center;}

div#newBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

div#topbar_button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 11%;
  height: 54%;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 41PX;
  margin-left: 75%;
  color: blue;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// window.onload = function() {

var header = document.getElementById('header');

var newBar = document.createElement('div');
newBar.id = "newBar";

var newBarText = document.createTextNode("Click on the link to go to Google");
newBar.appendChild(newBarText);

// create button and anchor tag and append
var topBarButton = document.createElement('div');
    topBarButton.id = "topbar_button";
var anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
    anchorTag.setAttribute('href', 'www.google.co.uk');
    topBarButton.appendChild(anchorTag);
    topBarButton.innerHTML = "Visit Google";

newBar.appendChild(topBarButton);

// append new top bar to header 
var header = document.getElementById('header');
header.parentNode.insertBefore(newBar, header);

// };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
topBarButton.appendChild(anchorTag);
topBarButton.innerHTML = "Visit Google";
```

you just replace the button with "Visit Google"

Comment: sould be anchorTag.innerHTML = "Visit Google";

Answer (score 0):

```
var anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
    anchorTag.setAttribute('href', 'www.google.co.uk');
    topBarButton.appendChild(anchorTag);
    topBarButton.innerHTML = "Visit Google";
```

Here you attached anchorTag to topBarButton and in next line making innerHTML to "Visit Google". Which is making anchorTag to be deleted. Change the code as below,

```
    var anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
            anchorTag.setAttribute('href', 'www.google.co.uk');
anchorTag.innerHTML = "Visit Google";
            topBarButton.appendChild(anchorTag);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what other said, you also needed to add "https://" to the URL, at least in CodePen.
Corrected JavaScript

```
// window.onload = function() {

var header = document.getElementById('header');

var newBar = document.createElement('div');
newBar.id = "newBar";

var newBarText = document.createTextNode("Click on the link to go to Google");
newBar.appendChild(newBarText);

// create button and anchor tag and append
var topBarButton = document.createElement('div');
    topBarButton.id = "topbar_button";
var anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
    anchorTag.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.google.co.uk');
    topBarButton.appendChild(anchorTag);
    anchorTag.innerHTML = "Visit Google";

newBar.appendChild(topBarButton);

// append new top bar to header 
var header = document.getElementById('header');
header.parentNode.insertBefore(newBar, header);

// };
```

In the CSS, you could add `#topbar_button a { text-decoration: none }` to get rid of the underline.